# How to make my subject/sender work with some tag i make

Tags: php, mail-sender

Hey i have make some tag on my sender to make it quite optionable `$usernameemail = preg_replace('/@.*?$/', '', $email);`
and i have been working with some array so its gonna work with ##UNAME## as the `$usernameemail` related, i want to make the tag ##UNAME##, but here the problem , when im putting these ##UNAME## on the message body , it turns out normally as (its should turn out from username@email.com to username) it working to put username , but it didnt work when im putting it on the subject, <s>any help would appreciate, hope my project gonna done. Thanks Alot!</s>

Comment: `str_replace('##UNAME##', $usernameemail, $body)`  Or you can do it as an array of tags to search for and an array of values to replace them with.

Comment: Hi @ArtisticPhoenix i have make a config to set my subject as in a config file without changing my sender,     ` "subject"        => "MakassarSender Function", ` i have set the uname , its just gonna work well if im using ##UNAME## as the calling the $usernameemail , but it didnt work if im using as the "subject" => "##UNAME##" , its just gonna send ##UNAME## on the subject

Comment: You should learn to abstract your issues, before googling them e.g. This for example has little to do with phpmailer. That's just string processing/substitution of placeholders.

Comment: it really have been frustating me for fixing this , making its as a mail sender with having so many tags , stackoverflow is the only site i can trust to help me i think

Comment: Sounds like you've been trying to apply those placeholders at various locations. But you've only shown one example of how you use it.

Comment: im trying to explain as my best, but language is my biggest problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
  $tags = [
      '##UNAME##' => $usernameemail,
      '##FOO##'   => $foo, //for example of multiple
  ];

  //$email is the content of the email (I would change this to $body as $email implies an email address)

  $email = str_replace(array_keys($tags), $tags, $email);
```

What this does is find the `keys` like `##UNAME##` in the `$email` text, and replaces it with the value for that key from the array.  This way it's easy to keep your tags organized etc..

Comment: can u check my answer below? , using it because have to post some of my script

Comment: You should edit your question and post the code there, doing it as an answer makes it confusing to other users and discourages other answers.

Comment: Sorry, first time using stackoverflow, i will try better next time.

Comment: I will let it go this time, just don't do it again.... Ha ha, just playing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $usernameemail = preg_replace('/@.*?$/', '', $email);

$date = date('G:i, d M Y');
$file = file_get_contents($msgfile);
$arr  = array('##EMAIL##', '##SUBJECT##', '##RANDOMIP##', '##FROMMAIL##', '##FROMNAME##', '##LINK##', '##RANDOMCHAR1##', '##RANDOMCHAR2##', '##RANDOMCHAR3##', '##RANDOMCHAR4##', '##RANDOMCHAR5##', '##RANDOMCHAR6##', '##RANDOMCHAR7##', '##RANDOMCHAR8##', '##RANDOMCHAR9##', '##RANDOMCHAR10##', '##COUNTRY##', '##DATE##', '##NUMBER1##', '##NUMBER2##', '##NUMBER3##', '##NUMBER4##', '##NUMBER5##', '##NUMBER6##', '##NUMBER7##', '##NUMBER8##', '##NUMBER9##', '##NUMBER10##', '##OS##', '##BROWSER##', '##CITYAMERIKA##', '##AMPLOP##', '##UNAME##');
$new  = array('' . $email . '', '' . $subject . '', '' . $randip . '', '' . $frommail . '', '' . $fromname . '', '' . $randurls . '', '' . $randstr1 . '', '' . $randstr2 . '', '' . $randstr3 . '', '' . $randstr4 . '', '' . $randstr5 . '', '' . $randstr6 . '', '' . $randstr7 . '', '' . $randstr8 . '', '' . $randstr9 . '', '' . $randstr10 . '', '' . $country . '', '' . $date . '', '' . $randnumber1 . '', '' . $randnumber2 . '', '' . $randnumber3 . '', '' . $randnumber4 . '', '' . $randnumber5 . '', '' . $randnumber6 . '', '' . $randnumber7 . '', '' . $randnumber8 . '', '' . $randnumber9 . '', '' . $randnumber10 . '', '' . $OS . '', '' . $browser . '', '' . $cityamrik . '', '' . $amplop . '', '' . $usernameemail . '');
$repl = str_replace($arr, $new, $file);
return $repl;
```

I have making a file to organize my tags , called mks.function.php , here i put all my tags to make it clean as possible. @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: you don't need to use all those *concentration operators* when creating your array, just a coma separated assignment is good enough... $new  = array ( $email, $subject, $randip, $frommail, $fromname, $randurls, $randstr1, $randstr2, $randstr3, $randstr4, $randstr5, $randstr6, $randstr7, $randstr8, $randstr9, $randstr10, $country, $date, $randnumber1, $randnumber2, $randnumber3, $randnumber4, $randnumber5, $randnumber6, $randnumber7, $randnumber8, $randnumber9, $randnumber10, $OS, $browser, $cityamrik, $amplop, $usernameemail ); other than that, are you sure $email has a value?

Comment: $ListBrowser = array('Internet Explorer', 'Firefox', 'Safari', 'Chrome', 'Edge', 'Opera', 'Netscape');
    shuffle($ListBrowser);
    $browser = array_shift($ListBrowser);

Comment: @Stephanie Temple have to use those because im making tags from shuffle the array, so making it is only option i got, and yes the $email has a value